# In Keepass is there any plugin or way to have a login form submitted?

Tags: security, password-management, keepass

In Keepass 2 is there any way to have it automatically log you into a website that it has been setup to do so? The only reason I use lastpass over Keepass is because it save me a great deal of time automatically filling in the log in credentials and submitting the form for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use KeePass 1.26 everyday and assuming that the functionality of KeePass 2.25 is identical then you can set it up to open a particular URL (e.g a bank website) using Ctrl+U. Having navigated to the login screen you can then use Autofill to place all the credentials in the correct fields and log you in using Ctrl+V. Hope this helps!